# Deriving extensions with multiparameter types

Tags: haskell, types, deriving, language-extension

I have an Ast type constructor, parameterized by the identifier type.
Using the DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable and DeriveTraversable extensions
it is possible to automatically create the appropriate instances.

Now I find it useful to introduce more type parameters but unfortunately
the above method doesn't scale. Ideally I would like to be able to
wrap my Ast type in selection types which would allow me to fmap to
the appropriate type parameters. Is there some way to achieve a similar
effect without having to define the instances myself?

edit:

Here is a small example of what the original Ast looked like:

```
Ast id = Ast (FuncDef id)
    deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

FuncDef id = FuncDef id [Fparam id] (Block id)
    deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

Block id = Block [Stmt id]
    deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

..
```

Comment: Could you add a minimized version of `Ast` along with some of the type parameters and typeclasses you want derived?

Comment: It's a neat idea.  My gut tells me you are beyond the automatic deriving mechanism's power, and it's time to start looking at [generics](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generics).

Comment: @luqui This is my conclusion too. The Deriving language extensions are there for a reason they don't seem to be powerful enough in this case.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling around all day I came to the following conclusions:

The Ast presented in the question turned out not to be very flexible.
In later stages I want to annotate different nodes in a way that can't
be expressed by just parameterizing the original Ast.

So I changed the Ast in order to act as a base for writing new types:

```
Ast funcdef = Ast funcdef
    deriving (Show)

Header id fpartype = Header id (Maybe Type) [fpartype]
    deriving (Show)

FuncDef header block = FuncDef header block
    deriving (Show)

Block stmt = Block [stmt]
    deriving (Show)

Stmt lvalue expr funccall = 
    StmtAssign lvalue expr |
    StmtFuncCall funccall |
    ..

Expr expr intConst lvalue funccall =
    ExprIntConst intConst |
    ExprLvalue lvalue |
    ExprFuncCall funccall |
    expr :+ expr |
    expr :- expr |
    ..
```

Now I can simply define a chain of newtypes for each compiler stage.
The Ast at the stage of the renamer may be parameterized around the identifier type:

```
newtype RAst id = RAst { ast :: Ast (RFuncDef id) }
newtype RHeader id = RHeader { header :: Header id (RFparType id) }
newtype RFuncDef id = RFuncDef { 
    funcDef :: FuncDef (RHeader id) (RBlock id) 
}
..
newtype RExpr id = RExpr { 
    expr :: Expr (RExpr id) RIntConst (RLvalue id) (RFuncCall id) 
}
```

During the typechecking stage the Ast may be parameterized by 
the different internal types used in the nodes.

This parameterization allows for constructing Asts with `Maybe` wrapped 
parameters in the middle of each stage.

If everything is ok we can use `fmap` to remove the `Maybe`s and prepare the tree for the next stage. There are other ways `Functor, Foldable` and `Traversable` are useful so these are a must to have.

At this point I figured that what I want is most likely not possible
without metaprogramming so I searched for a template haskell solution.
Sure enough there is the **genifunctors** library which implements generic
`fmap, foldMap` and `traverse` functions. Using these it's a simple matter
of writing a few newtype wrappers to make different instances of the required typeclasses around the appropriate parameters:

```
fmapGAst = $(genFmap Ast)
foldMapGAst = $(genFoldMap Ast)
traverseGast = $(genTraverse Ast)

newtype OverT1 t2 t3 t1 = OverT1 {unwrapT1 :: Ast t1 t2 t3 }
newtype OverT2 t1 t3 t2 = OverT2 {unwrapT2 :: Ast t1 t2 t3 }
newtype OverT3 t1 t2 t3 = OverT3 {unwrapT3 :: Ast t1 t2 t3 }

instance Functor (OverT1 a b) where
    fmap f w = OverT1 $ fmapGAst f id id $ unwrapT1 w

instance Functor (OverT2 a b) where
    fmap f w = OverT2 $ fmapGAst id f id $ unwrapT2 w

instance Functor (OverT3 a b) where
    fmap f w = OverT3 $ fmapGAst id id f $ unwrapT3 w

..
```